# Cannot Access Name Instance over VPN

Tags: sql-server

I am having an issue connecting to a SQL server instance with management studio over VPN.  I can connect to the default instance (i.e. SERVERNAME) over the VPN connection but I cannot connect to another instance on the same server (i.e SERVERNAME\INSTANCE) over the same VPN connection. All of the settings are the same in SQL Configuration manager.

Additionally, I can connect to the named instance just fine from any box "inside" the network. The error I am receiving is a general, "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred... Error 26."

Thanks

EDIT: I should also point out that I can use IPADDRESS to connect, but IPADDRESS\INSTANCE does not work.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/q/669372/66849 ?

Answer (score 0):

To (partially) resolve the situation you need to choose from one of these workarounds when connecting over VPN:

Enable and use SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows Authentication and a static port for the SQL Server instance (always specifying the port value in the connection string);

Use a static port for the SQL Server instance (always specifying the port value in the connection string), enable that TCP port in your server firewalls, and specify the public server name or its external IP address (provided that it is exposed outside the local network);

Enable trust between your source and destination domains (not applicable for connections “on the fly”).

Personally I decided to use the first workaround as it was the easier to implement and the most secure however If the problem persists, verify the server doesn't have an IPSEC policy that restricts access to the SQL Server port via IP address. That also could result in you being blocked.