# No connection to SQL Database with VB.net in VPN

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, vpn

I have problem with my sql connection. I would like to connect with my VB.net application with sql database placed on my server (external machine at other location). when I'm connected to normal internet all is works great. But when I'm trying to connect with the application to SQL database while I'm on Dual VPN net - ther's no connection.

Error appear:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not connecting to SQL Server over VPN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669372/not-connecting-to-sql-server-over-vpn)

Comment: Are you using an IP or name for the server address?

Comment: using ip for the server addresss

Comment: i also try using both ip 1) my server ip is 192.168.1.251 and 2) my VPN IP also but show same error