# How to access remote sql server via VPN?

Tags: sql, vpn

Well i am familiar with this kind of statement: "And i am gonna state the obvious here, but it is generally a bad idea to expose your sql server on the internet.. (unless you are using VPN)".
Ok then, if it's a bad idea, can anyone please show me how to do it via VPN? Please correct my question if i am wrong. Thank you!

PL: C#, SQL SERVER 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you will need is a VPN client. There are tons of them available, and few of them are even free. One such example of VPN client is LogmeIn (paid software for enterprise use). Please follow the steps mentioned in below link to setup LogmeIn VPN and share sql server database securely.

https://www.sixbitsoftware.com/docs/webhelp_prosb/Sharing_a_Database_Over_a_Virtual_Private_Network_(VPN).htm

Note: Assuming you want to know how to share a sql server database securely using VPN.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're running. Some/most server software applications have an option for it. Windows Server for example has [RRAS (Routing and Remote Access Services)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc770798(v=WS.10).aspx)

Related question: [Not connecting to SQL Server over VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669372/not-connecting-to-sql-server-over-vpn)