# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect my java Program to our SQLServer db that I access remotely by VPN, this DB uses windows authentication. I have sqljdbc4.jar in my libraries folder in Netbeans, also a jar file in the source packages tab(Not sure why its there). I think this problem is related to the VPN because I am pretty sure of all the credentials being used.

```
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://AAAHCSQL01:1433;databaseName=netForumAAAHCDev;";
    try{
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Here's the error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'MBisesi_AAAHC'. ClientConnectionId:92c25c9c-506b-4c77-88c3-819fc0774883
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at namedropper.NameDropper.main(NameDropper.java:23)
```

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669372/not-connecting-to-sql-server-over-vpn)?

Comment: I know for sure that I am connected to the database correctly as I have been working with for awhile. I am connected now because I can interact with it. My trouble is connecting my java program to the DB.

Comment: I cannot help you much on this, I'm not a MSSQL expert, sorry

Comment: I want to ask you about java I see your a certified master I passed oca I am trying to become a java developer. Can I pick your brain?

Comment: yes If you want, for this simply, ask to connect on linkedin and send me messages from there

Answer (score 0):

I use a VPN and have the same error for this jdbc driver.  Only difference is I run SQL Server in Mixed authentication mode.  I can say two things:

1. you may need to add instanceName to your connect string (see below).
2. try using jtds, its the only driver I could get to work (note my example assumes hibernate).

WORKS

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://****:1433;instance=***;DatabaseName=***;</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username”>***</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password”>***</property>
```

DOESN’T WORK

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://****:1433;instanceName=***;DatabaseName=***</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username”>***</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password”>***</property>
```

## EDIT

- Note: upgrading SQL Server 2008 R2 to SP3 did not enable the MS driver to work.  Also, [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication/) link may be help.